# Script to get the HTML files of a URL list, save them and convert them to an image

Tags: image, web-crawler

I am looking for an application or a script, either for Linux or Mac OS X, to retrieve the HTML files of a set of URLs (only the root HTML file), save them to a file and convert the HTML to an image. Anyone? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use
http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php

to render an snapshot image of any page.

You need to post the form and wait for returned html.

find http://renderer.geotek.de/image.php? in the HTML code.

you'll find imgid and browser just next to it extract the full url
and again using this URL. you'll get the image!!!!!!!!!!!!

Save it...

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's possible to call http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php dynamically, by submitting the URL in the query string or doing something similar. Do you know if it is possible?